# downloading audio files into iTunes

Tags: audio, download, itunes

How can I offer audio downloads that go straight into iTunes or their default music client rather than just downloading a file that has to be manual placed into their iTunes music folder?

This may be something really simple, just don't the answer. - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.

http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/

Comment: I can't do it that way I don't think. We're working directly with bands and artists selling their songs from our site. They don't want these downloads being sold through iTunes but we'd like the downloads to automatically download into iTunes. It's kinda backwards I know and I can't say I agree with the method but unfortunately I'm not in charge of that end of things. LOL

Comment: Sounds like you would need to execute code on the users end to manage the download and import into media player/itunes process. If you use a webbrowser, they're just going to 'save as' and 'open with' like any other download. Good luck!

Comment: And, DAAP isn't at all what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Digital Audio Access Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Audio_Access_Protocol).  This describes HTTP headers you can use to tell the client about the kind of content they're downloading.  Then your browser can say "hey, should I delegate this to another app?  Oh, iTunes handles that type?  OK, bro, here you go!"